# Why does BUILD-MAX-HEAP take time O(n) while HEAP-SORT takes O(nlgn) time?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, time, heap

While I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms", I was wondering why `HEAPSORT` takes time O(nlgn), whereas `BUILD-MAX-HEAP` takes time O(n).

The `HEAPSORT` begins its for loop at A.length downto 2, calling `MAX-HEAPIFY`.

The `BUILD-MAX-HEAP` begins its for loop at the floor of A.length/2 downto 1, calling `MAX-HEAPIFY`.

The `MAX-HEAPIFY` takes time O(lgn). I was wondering what causes `BUILD-MAX-HEAP` more faster than `HEAPSORT`.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) for a proof why heapifying is O(n).

Comment: Heapsort essentially starts with a MAX-HEAPIFY yes (though it may be formulated slightly differently at times), however, heapsort then goes on to *remove every element from the heap*. It is that extra step that makes it O(n log n) instead of just O(n).

Answer (score 1):

In building a heap, we always "HEAPIFY" the element starting from the bottom, but when sorting it, we always "HEAPIFY" the top most element. In both the case, the height is varying but point to note:

****In building a heap, maximum elements which we heapify lie at the bottom and they get very less height to heapify hence O(n), but while sorting we always heapify top most element. Even though the height is decreasing it is not as advantageous as in the prior case. ****

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

In the heapsort algorithm, you always worry about the "heap condition" which states that no element should be placed in the heap above a greater element, and if there is such an element violating the heap condition, then you fix it. How much effort it takes to fix the heap condition depends on how high above the bottom the element is that needs fixing.

In the inital phase where the heap is built, the last half of the elements don't violate the heap condition because there is nothing below. One quarter of the elements violate the heap condition, but are just one row above the bottom of the heap, so only one step is needed to fix the heap condition. Then one eighth of the elements violate the heap condition, but are just two rows above the bottom of the heap, so only two steps are needed.

If you add up the number of steps needed, you get n/4 * 1 + n/8 * 2 + n/16 * 3 + n/32 * 4 ... which adds up to less than n. But when you then sort by repeatedly putting the first element with the largest number at the end of the array, the heap condition is *always* violated at the top of the heap, (log n) rows above the bottom, so log n steps are needed to fix the heap condition.